# Executing named `fat arrow` from .then() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Success gets called in a successful factory response in the `then` callback:

This doesn't work, it cannot find `response`:

```
this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success(response), failure());
```

How to I pass the response to the `success` function correctly?

```
var success = (response: any): void => {
    scope.safes = response.data.safes;
    localStorage.setItem('safeCount', scope.safes.length);
    this.$http.get('/app/dashboard/safes/safes.html', { cache: this.$templateCache }).success((tplContent): void => {
        element.replaceWith(this.$compile(tplContent)(scope));
    }); 
}
```

The long hand version works fine, but I feel like it is very messy.

```
this.storeFactory.getSafes().then((response: any): void => {
    scope.safes = response.data.safes;
    localStorage.setItem('safeCount', scope.safes.length);
    this.$http.get('/app/dashboard/safes/safes.html', { cache: this.$templateCache }).success((tplContent): void => {
        element.replaceWith(this.$compile(tplContent)(scope));
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question or anything, but I wanted to clarify for you that this isn't a TypeScript syntax. It's ES2015 syntax. It's pure JavaScript, just newer. TypeScript happens to implement it.

Comment: good point, I'm in the middle of javascript conversion to typescript and starting ES6 (2015)

Comment: Your first attempt is fine. You could actually write  `var success = (response: any): void => { ... }` if you want to indicate that the function is not returning anything. The problem must be somewhere else

Comment: @BrunoGrieder It must be where I'm calling it: `this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success, failure);` If I add `success()` I get an error

Comment: question edited to more reflect the hurdle

Comment: Is it because you are actually calling `success` during the `then`'s execution rather than passing it back?  So `.then( success )` vs `.then( success())?

Comment: @jusopi. I have the `reponse` in the success call inside the `.then()`. It doesn't know what `response` is

Comment: at least in the case of angular's `$q` implementation, callbacks get passed back the `.then`'s response as parameters during the callback's execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to I pass the `response` to the `success` function correctly?

*You* don't. You pass the `success` function to the `then` method, then *the promise will pass* the result value to your `success` function. That's how callbacks work.

All you need to do is declare `response` as a paramter of your function. *You* must not call the function yourself - you only should pass it as a callback:

```
this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success, failure);
```

---

Also you will need to define the functions before you pass them to `then`. If you only declare them, and pass `undefined` values to `then`, they will be ignored. Use

```
var success = (response: any): void => {
    scope.safes = response.data.safes;
    localStorage.setItem('safeCount', scope.safes.length);
    this.$http.get('/app/dashboard/safes/safes.html', { cache: this.$templateCache }).success((tplContent): void => {
        element.replaceWith(this.$compile(tplContent)(scope));
    });
};

var failure = (): void => {
    this.$http.get('/app/shared/mocks/tableError.html', { cache: this.$templateCache }).success((tplContent): void => {
        element.replaceWith(this.$compile(tplContent)(scope));
    });
}

this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success, failure);
```

However, arrow functions are actually supposed to be defined inline, without assigning them to a specific variable. (You called this the "long hand version" in your question, even if it's actually shorter). Just use that and you won't face these problems.

In general, I would recommend to avoid defining functions in variable assignments completely. If you need a variable, just [use a declaration instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) (Typescript syntax should not vary much).

Comment: I would've thought variable hoisting would have not required you to place them above the `.then()` statement

Comment: It does that only for function declarations. If you just declare a variable and later assigna an arrow function to it, it will be `undefined` until that. Use `let` to avoid such bugs (it'll throw when used before initialised) - if Typescript does support that much of ES6.

Comment: Yes TypeScript is a 'superset` of ES6 should have all features. Question now becomes how to create ES6 declarative functions instead of assignments. Thanks again

Comment: http://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/ Arrow functions are always anonymous... I'd need to define them above if I want to use arrow syntax

Comment: @JonHarding: [Some features](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html#let-in-closures) are not implemented though… but basic `let` should work. Also see my updated answer.

Comment: That makes sense I guess I was trying too hard to keep this `this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success, failure);` clean. Thank you for all the resources I learned a ton through this.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the ES2015 syntax or Typescript, however the way you're passing back your `success` callback looks suspect.

**instead of**

```
this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success(response), failure());
```

**you should use**

```
this.storeFactory.getSafes().then(success, failure);
```

Comment: I have that, however, it doesn't know what `response` is

Comment: @JonHarding: You mean in the `success(response)` call, or in the typecheck?

Comment: 'cannot find name `response`'

Comment: Yeah I don't know how this applies to Typescipt, I just know how it looks to me as a coffeescript guy and the biggest difference is that you're calling the function so that it's acting like it wants to pass the *thenable* response back to the return value of your success callback.

Comment: @JonHarding: Well yes, because there is no name `response` in scope. The response value will come from the promise, and be passed to the callback by the `then` method. You only need to define the callback function and declare your parameters. This is what this answer suggests.

Comment: I completely agree, however when I use suggested syntax success and failure seem to get defined but not executed

Comment: @JonHarding: You did define them before you called `then`, right?

Comment: `.then( function(rsp){ success(rsp), failure(rsp) });` how about this then?

Comment: @jusopi: You mean `.then(function(rsp){ success(rsp); }, function(err) { failure(err); })`

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the correction.  I'm so accustomed to using `.then` only for *successful* callbacks and `.catch` only for *error* callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The callback of your AJAX call also needs to use arrow functions:

```
this.$http.get('/app/dashboard/safes/safes.html', { cache: this.$templateCache }).success((tplContent) => {
    element.replaceWith(this.$compile(tplContent)(scope));
});
```

Comment: any examples would be helpful

Comment: @JonHarding -- Does using the arrow syntax above not fix the issue (or, what kind of example are you looking for?)